# Commenting answered but not accepting

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

I've noticed quite frequently that (especially new) users don't mark answers as the accepted answer, but only comment it. For example just today you have [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53465558/3484879) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53468555/merge-two-queries-and-having-no-relation/53468725?noredirect=1#comment93808792_53468725).

Accepting an answer as the solution is obviously up to the OP but do answers like these gets accredited by mods/the powers that be? I can understand that this wouldn't be the case if the OP hasn't commented that the question is answered, however, when they comment to say it does and then don't why is a question with a confirmed answer left as unanswered?

This isn't about the points (if you're here just for the points, you have the wrong attitude in my opinion) but for others. When I'm searching for a solution to a question I have, the topics I visit first are those with accepted answers; as those are the ones that are likely to have a solution. I'm sure I'm not the only one who operates like that. As a result, I, or anyone, could miss a very good and informative answer, because the OP has verbally confirmed the answer, but not (taken the time to?) clicked the button.

Perhaps it more a UI thing? Is the accept answer as solution that obvious to (new) members over leaving a comments? I ask very few questions on SO (mainly as I almost always find a question very similar to my own, with an accepted answer and it solves the problem) so honestly I'm not sure; although I'll see the layout if/when someone replies with an answer. Maybe if more people only commented and didn't accept the answers as a solution my experience would be less like that? Unknown.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194061/is-it-acceptable-to-ask-for-upvote-accept-in-an-answer-when-submitting-it

Comment: @HansPassant I would suggest the linked topic is more related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14994/do-you-feel-dirty-if-you-nudge-new-users-to-accept-your-answer-when-they-indicat

Comment: Maybe it is better for everyone... Sometimes OP accepts answer that is just wrong and from now on bad answer takes top spot...

Answer (score 7):

> Accepting an answer as the solution is obviously up to the OP but do answers like these gets accredited by mods/the powers that be?

Nope, if the answer is not accepted, even if the person asking the question said "thank you, it works!", the mods can't mark the answer as accepted.

When the person asking tells you in the comments "thank you, it works!!", you can just reply with:

> I'm glad my answer helped you! Please consider [marking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it as correct so it can help other people checking this question also! :)

There is nothing wrong in saying that, because first some new users do not read the guidelines and second it will help the community in the long run if he/she marks it as correct.

Answer (score 2):

> Accepting an answer as the solution is obviously up to the OP but do answers like these gets accredited by mods/the powers that be?

Nobody besides the OP can accept an answer but everyone else can still “accredit” answers by upvoting. I trust upvotes more than I do the check mark since all the votes come from different people. Going by votes will also give you more options since only up to one answer can be accepted but multiple can be upvoted.  I also look at the comments to see if anyone found any problems with the answer, since you can’t always tell based off votes alone if there are any drawbacks.

Since most questions, even those with awesome answers, don’t have an accepted answer you are missing out on a lot so you might want to just search for questions that have any answers with `Answers:1`.